# rsync with remove extra lines in destination

Tags: rsync

First of all I give my directory structure in detail below.

```
src
   1
     1_1.txt
        test_line1
     1_2.txt
        test_line1
   2
     2_1.txt
        test_line1
     2_2.txt
        test_line1
```

I synchronised this `src` directory with `dst` directory. So now `dst` directory is same as `src` directory using following `rsync` command.

```
rsync -av src/* dst/
```

Well. If I add a line any of the file existing in `src` directory, the same command copies the changes in that `dst` directory.

Now I adding extra text line in `1_2.txt` at `dst` directory. In this case, `src` and `dst` directory are not same.

If I run the above `rsync` command I thought it will remove that extra line from that file at `dst` directory. But It didn't happen.

1. What should I do to keep files are same as `src` directory with `dst` directory?
2. When a new directory/file added in `dst` directory manually, It should prompt to remove that directory/file or not when I run `rsync` command. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not reproduce the same behaviour that you are seeing:

```
$ tree
.
|-- d
|   `-- file
`-- s
    `-- file

2 directories, 2 files
```

```
$ cat s/file
hello
```

```
$ rsync -av s/ d
sending incremental file list

sent 63 bytes  received 12 bytes  150.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6  speedup is 0.08
```

No data was transferred, the two files were already the same.

```
$ echo world >>d/file
$ cat d/file
hello
world
```

```
$ rsync -av s/ d
sending incremental file list
file

sent 116 bytes  received 35 bytes  302.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6  speedup is 0.04
```

```
$ cat d/file
hello
```

This shows that lines added to files in the destination directory will be removed by re-running `rsync -a`.

---

To delete files in the destination that are not available in the source directory, use `--delete`:

```
$ tree
.
|-- d
|   |-- extra_file
|   `-- file
`-- s
    `-- file

2 directories, 3 files
```

```
$ rsync -av --delete s/ d
sending incremental file list
deleting extra_file
./

sent 66 bytes  received 29 bytes  190.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6  speedup is 0.06
```

```
$ tree
.
|-- d
|   `-- file
`-- s
    `-- file

2 directories, 2 files
```

The `rsync` utility does not natively support interactive prompting for confirmation before deleting files on the destination.  You may however run with `--dry-run` first to see what would happen if you ran the copy for real.

---

Also note that if you use `rsync -av s/* d` rather than `rsync -av s/ d`, then you will not copy any hidden file or directory in the source directory.  This is because the `*` glob pattern by default does not expand to hidden filenames.  Hidden files in the subdirectories of the source directory would still be copied though.

Comment: Thank you. If rsync can delete a directory/file in a destination directory, Could It do prompt a warning message saying 'Do you really want to delete this Folder or File?' before deleting that directory/file?

Comment: @SmithDwayne I just added a bit of text about this. No, `rsync` does not support this. You can do a dry-run first though, to see what would happen. To do anything more than that would require wrapping `rsync` in some sort of script.  This would be a too big project for me to undertake (and get right) at the moment.